# What is the difference between cXML and XML? Will XML tools work with cXML?

Tags: .net, xml, cxml

I'm suddenly working with cXML and I have a few question about it.

What is the difference between cXML and regular XML?

Can I use XML tools on cXML?

Is there anything recommended to work with cXML in a .NET stack?

Answer (score 3):

XML is a generic standard for encoding any kind of information.

cXML is a specific XML vocabulary. There are thousands of XML vocabularies: fPML for financial transactions, XBRL for reporting financial results, MusicXML for digital music, MathXML for mathematics, XHTML for web pages, SVG for vector graphics, JATS for scientific articles. They are all XML, but they use different element and attribute names with different meanings. Because they are all XML, you can use generic XML tools with any of these vocabularies.

As for specific tools that understand cXML, I can't help you.